# How to declare p.ABC to be a path in METAPOST

Tags: metapost

In METAPOST, is there a way to declare that *any* expression of the form `p.ABC` is a path?

(I guess *no*, but maybe there is a trick.)

Comment: Can you please explain your question a bit better? You can definitely declare paths in MetaPost, see e.g. the `triangle` path in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510613.

Comment: I don't think you can. The best you can do is using a `vardef`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat anything like `p.ABC`, or `p.whateveryouwanttowrite` should be a path

Comment: OK, it would have been nice if you explained your question a bit better. One has to *guess* that "of this form" means "contains a period".

Comment: @egreg how would you do it? (sorry I am new to METAPOST)

Comment: I didn't say I would do it. `;-)`. Seriously, what's your aim?

Comment: @egreg [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), I presume.

Comment: @egreg what is my aim: I use it to draw illustrations for plane geometry; I use `z.A`--`z.Z` for points and it would be natural to use `p.a`--`p.z` for paths; unfortunately I have to declare each path separately.

Comment: As I suspected, Hungarian notation.  Please refer to the Wikipedia page for why this is completely useless.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I think it is better to be consitent --- if it is good for points, it should be good for paths.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I see.  Only `numeric` is implicit in MetaPost (that is why `z0 = (1,2)` works).  I don't think you can have implicit paths.

Comment: You could use something like this `vardef newpath@#(expr somepath) = if not path path p@#: path p@#; fi; p@# := somepath; enddef;` and use it to create new paths without declaring them `newpath.AB((0,0)--(100,100)); draw p.AB;`. But this may not worth the effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can *almost* do this, following an idea on p.289 of *The Metafont Book*.

Provided you don't mind using uppercase `P` to define a `path` and lowercase `p` to use it, then you could just do this:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

def P suffix $ = path p.$; p.$ enddef;

beginfig(1);

 P.AnotherOne = ((up..down) scaled 42);
 P.ABC = origin .. 40 right rotated 50 .. 100 right rotated -30;

 draw p.ABC;

 drawarrow p.AnotherOne withcolor blue;
 drawarrow p.AnotherOne rotated 30 withcolor red;

endfig;
end.
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, we can do better than this.

My original effort was to add some `if not known` logic like this:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

def p suffix $ = if not known p.$: path p.$; fi p.$ enddef;

beginfig(1);

 p.AnotherOne = ((up..down) scaled 42);
 p.ABC = origin .. 40 right rotated 50 .. 100 right rotated -30;

 draw p.ABC;

 drawarrow p.AnotherOne withcolor blue;
 drawarrow p.AnotherOne rotated 30 withcolor red;

endfig;
end.
```

but with `mpost 2.00 (TeXLive 2019)` that just gives a SIGSEGV Address Boundary Error segmentation fault.  I guess that this is because I am trying to use the symbol `p` in its own definition.  But there is a simple change to make it work:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

def p suffix $ = if not known p_.$: path p_.$; fi p_.$ enddef;

beginfig(1);

 p.AnotherOne = ((up..down) scaled 42);
 p.ABC = origin .. 40 right rotated 50 .. 100 right rotated -30;

 draw p.ABC;

 drawarrow p.AnotherOne withcolor blue;
 drawarrow p.AnotherOne rotated 30 withcolor red;

endfig;
end.
```

This makes `p<suffix>` expand to a token called `p_<suffix>`; and if the
token has not been defined before, it is automatically declared to be a path.  I think that this is what the OP wanted.

But users can be grateful to @AntonPetrunin for pointing out that other macros (for example `hatchfill` from [hatching.mp](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hatching) also use `p_` for temporary paths, which can lead to strange problems, so a safer definition is something like this

```
def p suffix $ = if not known tt_p_.$: path tt_p_.$; fi tt_p_.$ enddef;
```

where `tt_` is whatever extra prefix you like.

### Notes

- We can't use the regular `save` mechanism here, because the whole point of this rigmarole is to make tt_p_. visible globally.  So we run the risk of a clash of global variable when we use other macro packages.
- The defintion `def p ...` means that the token `p` has become a *spark* (a token with an active meaning), so you *can't* use it as a *tag* any more.   See [The Metafont Book](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfbook) for details.

Comment: Why not `def p suffix $ = if not known p_.$: path p_.$; fi p_.$ enddef;` ?

Comment: @Thruston I don't get a segmentation fault.  Can you post a reproducer, please?

Comment: The last one works perfectly if I add "fill p.ABC..cycle;" BUT if I add "input hatching" and "hatchfill p.ABC..cycle  withcolor (20, 1mm, -.2bp);" then it does not work (and I cannot understand the error message).

Comment: @AntonPetrunin - the problem is that both hatchfill and my macro use `p_` -- hatchfill does `path p_` every time you call it, which wipes out my `p_` path...

Comment: Sorry for bugging you --- how one could modify the definition so that I could still use z.p for a point?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin you can't.  I've updated the answer.  Once you define a token with `def` you can no longer use it as a suffix.  So pick a different suffix.